# How does Git(Hub) handle possible collisions from short SHAs?

Tags: git, cryptography, github, sha

Both Git and GitHub display short versions of SHAs -- just the first 7 characters instead of all 40 -- and both Git and GitHub support taking these short SHAs as arguments.

E.g. `git show 962a9e8`

E.g. https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/962a9e8

Given that the possibility space is now orders of magnitude lower, "just" [268 million](http://www.google.com/search?q=16%5E7), how do Git and GitHub protect against collisions here? And how do they handle them?

Comment: This would not be a concern at the level of GitHub because sha1's are unique to each individual project.

Comment: It's still entirely possible for two 7-character short sha1s to collide within a single project.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to grab commits via github's API with short SHA... For instance, https://github.com/alexnaspo/var_dumpling-chrome/commit/9e9726ac returns the commit I need, but https://api.github.com/repos/alexnaspo/var_dumpling-chrome/git/commits/9e9726ac does not

Answer (score 70, accepted):

These short forms are just to simplify visual recognition and to make your life [easier](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection). Git doesn't really truncate anything, internally everything will be handled with the complete value. You can use a partial SHA-1 at your convenience, though:

> Git is smart enough to figure out what commit you meant to type if you provide the first few characters, as long as your partial SHA-1 is at least four characters long and unambiguous — that is, only one object in the current repository begins with that partial SHA-1.

Comment: Thanks! That link elaborates further: "Git can figure out a short, unique abbreviation for your SHA-1 values. If you pass `--abbrev-commit` to the git log command, the output will use shorter values but keep them unique; it defaults to using seven characters but makes them longer if necessary to keep the SHA-1 unambiguous."

Comment: Another useful quote: "Generally, eight to ten characters are more than enough to be unique within a project. One of the largest Git projects, the Linux kernel, is beginning to need 12 characters out of the possible 40 to stay unique."

Comment: Your link is broken... :(

Comment: @emboss I think the question is not about is git smart enough. Let's assume you have a CI/CD which marks an artifact using a short form of commit SHA. In this case the smartness of git really does not matter.

Answer (score 35):

I have a repository that has a commit with an id of `000182eacf99cde27d5916aa415921924b82972c`.

```
git show 00018
```

shows the revision, but

```
git show 0001
```

prints

```
error: short SHA1 0001 is ambiguous.
error: short SHA1 0001 is ambiguous.
fatal: ambiguous argument '0001': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

(If you're curious, it's a clone of the git repository for git itself; that commit is one that Linus Torvalds made in 2005.)

Comment: If you need to know which objects are matched with your ambiguous id (`0001` in this case), you can do `git rev-list --all --objects | grep ^0001`. After you have list of possible full SHA1s, you can do `git show` for each one.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27428930/841555) shows how to disambiguate using only a git command.

Answer (score 14):

Two notes here:

- If you type <kbd>y</kbd> anywhere on the GitHub page displaying a commit, you will see the full 40 bytes of said commit.
  That illustrates [emboss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827060/emboss)'s point: GitHub doesn't truncate anything.
- And 7 hex digits (28 bits) isn't enough since 2010 anyway.
  See [commit dce9648](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dce96489162b05ae3463741f7f0365ff56f0de36) by Linus Torwalds himself (Oct 2010, git 1.7.4.4):

> The default of 7 comes from fairly early in git development, when seven hex digits was a lot (it covers about 250+ million hash values). Back then I thought that 65k revisions was a lot (it was what we were about to hit in BK), and each revision tends to be about 5-10
>   new objects or so, so a million objects was a big number.

(BK = BitKeeper)

> These days, the kernel isn't even the largest git project, and even the kernel has about 220k revisions (*much* bigger than the BK tree ever was) and we are approaching two million objects. At that point, seven hex digits is still unique for a lot of them, but when we're
>   talking about just two orders of magnitude difference between number of objects and the hash size, there *will* be collisions in truncated hash values. It's no longer even close to unrealistic - it happens all the time.
>
> We should both increase the default abbrev that was unrealistically small, *and* add a way for people to set their own default per-project in the git config file.

Comment: I'm curious, what *is* the largest git project? Or at least, what are some of the best examples out there of absolutely massive git repos?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo As mentioned in http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/, you have 2 kinds of huge repos (huge history, or huge binaries) An example of huge git repo was the Facebook one: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7648237 (they switched since then to their own version of Mercurial)

Comment: You mean 7 hex digits (28 bits), not 7 bits.

Comment: @ThomasJacob Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasJacob Note: SHA1 won't always be the default hash algorithm used in Git. This is evolving: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309