# Git hash duplicates

Tags: git, hash, probability

Git allows to retrieve the hash of the commit with commands like:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

which gives `33b316c`
or

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

which gives `33b316cbeeab3d69e79b9fb659414af4e7829a32`
I know that long hashes in practice will never collide.

In practice, the short hashes are used much more often. I'd like to know what's the probability for the short ones to collide? Does git take any measures to overcome possible collisions (when for example using `git checkout`)?

Comment: The first bit is pretty basic math, just [size of alphabet]^[number of characters]. So `16^length`. Any measures would likely have to be dug up from source code, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Git(Hub) handle possible collisions from short SHAs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128444/how-does-github-handle-possible-collisions-from-short-shas)

Comment: It really is just that bit of math. git internally only uses the long hash, collisions of the short hash don't matter. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128444/how-does-github-handle-possible-collisions-from-short-shas

Answer (score 7):

I give a formula in my [book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf)—see pp. 78-79—but if you're looking for a simple one, the point at which the probability of *some* hash collision reaches about 50% in an n-bit hash is when you hash roughly 2<sup>n/2</sup> keys.  The SHA-1 hash itself is 160 bits, represented as 40 hexadecimal digits, each representing 4 of the 160 bits.  Truncating that to 7 hexadecimal digits leaves 28 bits, so you will reach 50%-chance-of-collision at about 2<sup>14</sup> keys, or 16384 objects.  If you constrain the objects to be only commits, that's a pretty decent number of commits, but Git places all objects—commits, trees, annotated tag objects, and blobs—in a single hash-indexed key-value store.

The probability of the hashes of *any given pair* of keys colliding is just 1 in 2<sup>n</sup>, i.e., 1 in 2<sup>28</sup> or 1 out of 268 million.  The reason it increases so fast to 50%, as the number of keys grows, is known as the Birthday Paradox or [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  50% is of course far too scary; with 28 bits, if we want the overall probability to be below 0.1%, we should keep the number of objects below about 1230.  By going to 32 bits (8 character abbrevations) we double this to about 2460, but that's still not very many objects.

By the time you have 16k objects in your store, you probably should use at least 10 hexadecimal digits, giving 2<sup>40</sup> possible hash values and a p-bar value of about .99987794... (about .019% chance of collisions).  Nine hex digits gives only 2<sup>36</sup> hash values, producing a p-bar of .99804890... or 0.19% chance of collision, which I think is too high.

If you can restrict your ambiguous-matching code to only commits—or only *commit-ish*, which in Git means *commits or annotated tags*—the built in defaults work pretty well.  (Git will in fact do this in a lot of cases.)  But Git's internal code for computing the "right" abbreviation length is, at least in my opinion, far too care-free, too ["loosey-goosey"](https://www.yourdictionary.com/loosey-goosey), as it uses the 50%-collision-probability square-root trick in contexts where the resulting hash might be used to identify *any* object.

(As noted in comments, *internally* Git always uses the full hashes.  It's only at the not-Git / Git interface, e.g., `git log <hash>` or `git show <hash>` user-facing commands, that you can type in an abbreviated hash, or ask for an abbreviated output hash.  Here Git will default to using the 50%-collision-probability number to compute how many characters to show, starting with an estimate of the number of objects in the database.  If you're supplying the hash, *you* choose how much to supply.  If you're asking Git to provide it, you can still choose how much, with `--abbrev=number`.  Note that there's an absolute minimum of 4: `git log abc` won't treat `abc` as a hash ID, but `git log abcd` will treat `abcd` as an abbreviated a hash ID.  There's also a very old default of 7 characters, from the Git 1.7-ish days.)

Answer (score 3):

The chances of having duplicates in the list of a repo's short hashes increase very fast with the number of commits.

However, it doesn't cause too many problems since these are not at all meant to be unique, they're only a comfort feature, providing an alternative way to designate commits in some commands.

When you choose to feed a command a short hash and it actually *is* ambiguous in your repo (i. e. can't be resolved to a unique commit), git prompts you with a list of candidates and you get to choose which you intended to call.

Example output :

```
$ git checkout 2334
error: short SHA1 2334 is ambiguous
hint: The candidates are:
hint:   233475fec8 commit 2018-02-14 - Merge pull request #175 in someRepo from someBranch to someOtherBranch
hint:   2334790f05 commit 2018-06-14 - Merge pull request #917 in someRepo from someBranch to yetAnotherBranch
hint:   233415cfa2 tree
hint:   233438d772 tree
hint:   23348a014a tree
error: pathspec '2334' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

This is for `git checkout <shortHash>` typed in the CLI for example, but I'm unsure as to how it behaves in the context of a script. Either it errors with an exit code 1 or it automatically takes one of the candidates, I'll have to check that.

Comment: `git checkout <hash>` treats the hash as a `tree-ish`, so you should count the number of non-blob objects to approximate the probably of collisions for any given hash subset and number of objects.  How many trees there are depends on a lot of factors: a bushy set of pathnames produces more trees per commit, but if there are few changes in a commit, and they're restricted to one particular sub-tree, many of those trees will be shared across many commits...